# why scrapy selector.css retuen blank list

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
    def parse(self, response):
        sel=scrapy.Selector(response)
        items_list=sel.css('#main > div.containerbox.boxindex > div.layui-row.layui-col-space15 > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr')
```

the selector comes from copy->copy selector
i debuged the code,the response is correct.
i used `$$("selector")` in chrome and it's also correct
allowed_domains is correct
BUT items_list=[]

Comment: Please add some more info.

Comment: Please include the webpage on which you are applying these selectors, only then we'll be able to verify the selector and see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `.get()` and `.getall()` while using the CSS selector.

if you need to extract only the first element use `.get()`

```
items_list=sel.css('#main > div.containerbox.boxindex > div.layui-row.layui-col-space15 > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr').get()
```

or if you need extract all the element use `.getall()`

```
items_list=sel.css('#main > div.containerbox.boxindex > div.layui-row.layui-col-space15 > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr').getall()
```